# ListView in fragment doesn't show

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to populate a listView inside a fragment, with custom layout. But when i launch the application the content of listview is not loaded (this is obtained using an array adapter). 
Here the code where i load the listView:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_start, container, false);
        ProfilesDatabaseHelper dbHelper = ac.getDbManager();
        ProfileManagerDAO dbDao = ac.getProfileManagerDAO();
        //TODO mettere profilehandler dentroo profileapp.
        ProfileHandler handler = new ProfileHandler(view.getContext());
        Profile profile = handler.getCurrentProfile();
        TextView label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.labelvlm);
        label.setText("TEST");
        if(handler!=null){
            label.setText("Ring Volume: " + profile.getRingVolume() + "Max: " 
                    + handler.getMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
            label.append("\tVoice Call Volume: " + profile.getCallVolume()
                    + " Max: " + handler.getMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL));
            //manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 5, 0); 
            label.append("\tWIFI Status: " + handler.isWifiActive());           
        }
        Ringtone tone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(view.getContext(), Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        if(tone!=null){
            label.append("\n" + tone.getTitle(view.getContext()));  
        }
        SeekBar bar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ringtonevolumeBar);
        bar.setMax(handler.getMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));     
        bar.setProgress(profile.getRingVolume());
        ArrayList<String> profiles = ac.getProfileManagerDAO().getprofileNamesList();
        if(profiles!=null){
            Log.d(TAG, "List size: " + profiles.size());
            ListView profileslist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileslist);            
            adapter = new ProfilesArrayAdapter(view.getContext(), R.layout.list_item, profiles);
            profileslist.setAdapter(adapter);
//          List<String> testing = new ArrayList<String>();
//            testing.add("Hey");
//            testing.add("Hey Do");
//            testing.add("Hey It");
//            testing.add("Hey Please");
//            ArrayAdapter moviesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testing);
//            profileslist.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);
            //profileslist.setA
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Here the code of my CustomAdapter:

```
public class ProfilesArrayAdapter extends
    ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Integer>> {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> entries;
int resourceId;
Context context;

static class ProfileItemHandler {
    TextView profileId;
    TextView profileName;
}

public ProfilesArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<HashMap<String,Integer>> profiles) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId);
    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.entries = profiles;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ProfileItemHandler handler = null;
    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        handler = new ProfileItemHandler();
        handler.profileId = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        handler.profileName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.profileId);
        row.setTag(handler);
    } else {
        handler = (ProfileItemHandler) row.getTag();
    }
    HashMap<String, Integer> entry = this.getItem(position);
    for(String cur_entry: entry.keySet()){
        handler.profileId.setText(cur_entry);
        handler.profileName.setText(entry.get(cur_entry));
    }               
    return row;
}
```

}

And this is the xml for list item layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/profileId" android:text="TextView" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/profileName" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here the main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StartActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/labelvlm"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/ringtonevolumeBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/labelvlm"        
        android:layout_marginTop="122dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/profileslist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ringtonevolumeBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ringtonevolumeBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't receive any error message, but when i launch the application, no items are shown in listView, and the method getView of my Adapter is never called. Any idea?

Comment: I went through many questions on so about that issue, but none seems to solve my problem. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.
It was inside the constructor:

```
public ProfilesArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<HashMap<String,Integer>> profiles) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId);
    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.entries = profiles;
}
```

On the first line, the call to super constructor was wrong. 
In fact, the correct call should be:

```
super(context, layoutResourceId, profiles);
```

With that, now the list is populated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be (since you are getting no error messages) that this line:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> profiles = ac.getProfileManagerDAO().getprofileList();
```

**returns an empty ArrayList** with size = 0 or **null** in general. Therefore, your ListView contains no items and getView() is never called.

Could you please also post the layout files of your Fragment and of your Activity, as well as the onCreateView() method of your Fragment, and the onCreate() method of your Activity.

Furthermore, I am asking myself why this code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> profiles = ac.getProfileManagerDAO().getprofileList();
    if(profiles!=null){
        Log.d(TAG, "List size: " + profiles.size());
        ListView profileslist = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profileslist);           
        adapter = new ProfilesArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, profiles);
        profileslist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

is not inside the Fragments onCreateView() method?
In that way you would not call getActivity().findViewById(...) but you would **call inflatedview.findViewById(...) directly on the inflated layout**.

**Update:**
Does your Activity extend FragmentActivity? Where in your Activity's code is the Fragment "added" or "replaced" to the layout?

Comment: I checked, but the list is not empty, it contains exactly one element. That piece of code was originally inside onCreateView, but trying to solve that problem i moved inside the onCreateActivity method (that is called after onCreateView). I'll edit the answer to add the xml layout of the fragment.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is the "main layout" the layout file of the Activity or of the Fragment? Please post your Activity's onCreate() method and your Fragments onCreateView() method.

Comment: Done, i added as a comment a piece of code that works and show correctly the listView using a simple arrayAdapter.

Comment: The main layout is the layout that is loaded inside the Fragment.

Comment: I found the problem!!! I'll add an answer with the solution! But i give you +1 for your time. (As you will see the solution was something very stupid!!! Just my fault!!!)